# Deep Copy of CMImageBuffer or CVImageBuffer

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avcaptureoutput

Hi I am currently working on an app which needs to capture a Video and at the same time should be able to take frames to blend them.
The problem I am having is that my frames coming from:

```
func captureOutput(
     captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!,
     didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer:
     CMSampleBuffer!,
     fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!
)
```

will drop after blending about 10-12 frames. I tried blending every 10th frame but it will still drop after 10-12 blended frames.

I know that I should copy the CVImageBuffer to release the imageBuffer which I got using the following:
`let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)`

I also know that

```
func CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(
     _ allocator: CFAllocator?,
     _ sbuf: CMSampleBuffer,
     _ sbufCopyOut: UnsafeMutablePointer
) -> OSStatus
```

only creates shallow copies and won't help releasing the original imageBuffer

So my question is: How can I create a complete deep copy of a `CMSmapleBuffer` or `CVImageBuffer`?
I would like to use:

```
func CMSampleBufferCreate(
     _ allocator: CFAllocator?,
     _ dataBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?,
     _ dataReady: Bool,
     _ makeDataReadyCallback: CMSampleBufferMakeDataReadyCallback?,
     _ makeDataReadyRefcon: UnsafeMutablePointer,
     _ formatDescription: CMFormatDescription?,
     _ numSamples: CMItemCount,
     _ numSampleTimingEntries: CMItemCount,
     _ sampleTimingArray: UnsafePointer,
     _ numSampleSizeEntries: CMItemCount,
     _ sampleSizeArray: UnsafePointer,
     _ sBufOut: UnsafeMutablePointer
) -> OSStatus
```

But the function is a bit overwhelming and I don't know where to get all the attributes from.
I am sure I can take a lot from the given `CMSmapleBuffer`.

I've been looking for a solution for a couple of days now.
If you need more context please feel free to ask.
I hope somone can help.

Comment: Solved? ........